# Jmeter file upload using PUT not working

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to upload a file using the PUT method, which is not including the file in the request. I have followed the other example POST methods, but considering PUT does not allow multipart to be checked, that might be the issue.

I am also using:
* httpClient4
* jmeter 3.3

screenshot : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s126/sh/b4ebf947-c7e4-4e0a-9ebf-8e42a5f5d082/6813671cb2ab7419

Request data:

```
PUT http://myurl----here/app_path/test__16525587b4361f339ca33a9cdf0e9201d90e76dc__1676871c-71b8-488a-9750-29554a4be722

PUT data:


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Host: int-cloudstore-perf.svc.netspot.com.au
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/9.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test does't seem to be sending anything as your `Put data` should not be blank.

I would recommend to remove `data` from the `Parameter Name` section of the "Files Upload" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as [PUT method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) is different and it doesn't assume submitting an [HTML form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and most probably your request will start working as expected (at least it will send data to the server)

Just in case check out [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article

Comment: So far, i have tried : 
* With and without the "Parameter Name"
* Hard coded a file path, to be sure its finding one
* Switching the clients from http to java

I might have something to do with post not allowing multipart ? 

That link did help me, with a workaround using the "__filetostring" method, but I am not sure how that will behave with very large files. 

    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8
    ${__FileToString(${put_files_path}/${file_name})}